# Proof if $x$ is order $\phi(n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ all inverses are powers of $x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, totient-function

I wish to prove that if $x$ is order $\phi(n)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$, all its inverses are powers of $x$. Where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totient function that tells us how many invertible elements there are. Below is what I think is a good proof, but I am still learning and wish to grow:

First of all, there are precisely $\phi(n)< n$ invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$. We know that the product of two or more invertible elements is again invertible. The condition is that every single element is invertible. Now notice that we know that:

$$x^{\phi(n)} \equiv1 \mod n $$
Since $1$ is its own inverse, it is invertible, the same must then hold for $x^{\phi(n)}$. Since a product of $x$'s leads to an invertible element, we then also know that $x$ must be invertible. Observe that every power of $x$ is invertible, since it consists of a product of invertible elements, let us list them:

$$ 1, x^1, x^2, x^3 ... x^{\phi(n)-1} $$
There are precisely $\phi(n)$ such elements and they are all invertible. However, this is precisely the amount of invertible elements there were in $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$. We have therefore given a complete list and the full set of invertible elements is simply the list of powers of $x$.

Comment: The multiplicative group of the integers modulo $n$ is not necessarily cyclic.

Comment: @Wuestenfux, but the set of integers modulo $n$ which have inverses is, which is exactly what the question asks us to prove

Comment: Note that $x^ix^{\phi(n)-i}\;=x^{\phi(n)}$. So it automatically follows that $x^i$ is invertible. Have you shown that the elements $x^i$ are unique?

Comment: You mean: The unit group of the integers modulo $n$ is cyclic.

Comment: That is to say whenever $x^i=x^j \mod n$ it must be that $i=j$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: I didn't think of that, but that's a good thing to show.

Comment: Suppose $x ^i \equiv x^j \mod n$ then apply the inverse of $x^i$ and not that $ (x^i)^{-1} x^j=1 \mod n$ however this means  we are dealing with the same element, since inverses are unique $i=j$.

Comment: Am I correct in saying this?

Comment: When you have an element in a finite group such that the element and the group have the same order, then the subgroup generated by that element equals the whole group (you can even see this without Lagrange's Theorem, looking on the level of sets), so this element generates the whole group, and all of its inverses are powers of it.

Also, to address some comments above: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ isn't a group under multiplication, and so I assumed from the start that we're really talking about the group $\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^*$.